# How to install SUMOLIB using Python3?

Tags: python, sumo

I am working on a project which has SUMOLIB module as a dependency on , but I have no idea how to install it. I tried doing `pip install sumolib`, but it shows me that no such module exists.

Can someone tell me how to install SUMOLIB?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at the downloads page of Sumolib.
https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Downloads.html

Comment: Well, I checked the page but it still doesn't specify how to install it using pip and use it in an existing program.

Answer (score 0):

`sumolib` is installed as a part of the [SUMO package](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Downloads.html#sumo_-_latest_release_version_131). It can be found under `SUMO_HOME/tools/sumolib`.

To use `sumolib` in a script, check [here](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tools/Sumolib.html).